# Calling a function from within a data attribute in Bootstrap Typeahead?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Twitter bootstrap provides a special input element. But I'm trying to fill one of its attributes using javascript function.

```
<input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-source="return fun()">

<script>
function fun()
{
  return "["apple", "bananas"]";
}
</script>
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

**EDIT**:

Tried as pointed by Moin Zaman,

http://jsbin.com/enacof/5

But still doesn't work. :(

Comment: It looks like you have a typo - `data-provider` with an `r`

Comment: @Hogan No typo : it is `data-provide` **without** an `r` see [on github](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/v2.0.4/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js#L277)

Answer (score 1):

Your double quote usage is not quite right.

Try:

```
  return "['apple', 'bananas']";
```

Your code should be throwing a script error in the browser.

Also this won't work as the [Bootstrap Typeahead](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) reference and code shows that the `data-source` is used directly as a string and not `eval`'ed to run as a js function.

The other way to do it would be:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({source:"['apple', 'bananas']"})
```

You could also try:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({source: fun()})
```

or:

```
var data = fun();
$('.typeahead').typeahead({source: data})
```

Comment: Got me by 1/100th of a second... photo finish!

Comment: :) Doesn't matter. until an answer gets more votes, I think its random which answer gets shown up the top.

Comment: @MoinZaman - Well I gave you +1, you are only 230 from 10K and no one should have to wait long for that.

Comment: how did u know that you could use `.typeahead({source:"['apple', 'bananas']"})`. Is there a reference for it?

Comment: and should i leave html like this `data-source=""`

Comment: @LMV: at the bottom of the page I linked to under Methods, it says `typeahead(options)`

Comment: @LMV: I think you can safely remove the `data-source` attribute

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15251/discussion-between-lmv-and-moin-zaman)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is better?

```
  return '["apple", "bananas"]';
```